# How does systemd provide data to the service triggered by a socket?

Tags: systemd, rsyslog, systemd-journald

The concept behind systemd sockets is to provide a *"cheap listener service"* that will start the *"service that would normally bind that socket but we don't want to run it all the time"* once data on the socket is detected.

Once started why can the *"service that would normally bind that socket but we don't want to run it all the time"* now receive data from the socket?

---

[Background]

I don't want `rsyslog` to be started when there is data on `/run/systemd/journal/syslog`. I want to start it when I need it and don't understand why is it a bad practice to bind it directly to the socket and delete `syslog.socket` altogether.

Comment: Have you seen [the relevant systemd documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html)?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to start it when I need it"? It's arguably needed when there's log data in the socket for it to consume... Do you mean you want to start it unconditionally and have rsyslog listen on the socket directly, rather than use socket activation for it?

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger `Do you mean you want to start it unconditionally and have rsyslog listen on the socket directly, rather than use socket activation for it?` Yes. And all the docs imply the socket activation setup. So I'm trying to understand what could go wrong if I bypass systemd sockets.

Answer (score 2):

The [imuxsock](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imuxsock.html?highlight=imuxsock#imuxsock-systemd-details-label) plugin of rsyslog [appears to be aware](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/blob/dc2c3d7670c487c08b7809d7595537be82a0c20d/plugins/imuxsock/imuxsock.c#L1203) of systemd's socket activation.

Systemd will create the socket and the file descriptor of that listening socket will be passed to the rsyslog.socket service [which will use it](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/blob/dc2c3d7670c487c08b7809d7595537be82a0c20d/plugins/imuxsock/imuxsock.c#L567).